# Oracle 10g - Linking two views with different user privileges

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

I am new to this, so I apologise if I am not completely clear...

Background:
Ten staff members, all with the role `Teacher` assigned to them.

The `StaffDetails` table has 6 columns - `StaffID`, `StaffName`, `DateOfBirth`, `Gender`, `HolidayDaysRemaining` & `StaffRole`

I would like the teachers to see all of **their own** details, but only the `StaffID`, `StaffName` and `StaffRole` columns of **other** members of staff.

The code I already have is explained below:

Firstly, a view that shows the three columns that all staff members can see (`StaffID`, `StaffName`, `StaffRole`):

```
CREATE VIEW StaffDetailsForStaffMutual AS  
SELECT sd.StaffID, sd.StaffName, sd.StaffRole  
FROM StaffDetails sd;
```

Secondly, a view that will hold the columns `DateOfBirth`, `Gender`, and `HolidayDaysRemaining`. **These** will only be viewable by the person logged in (as shown by sub-query). The `StaffID` attribute is only included so that a common column is in both views - it will be present only once in the final table.

```
CREATE VIEW StaffXDetailsForStaffX AS  
SELECT sd.StaffID, sd.DateOfBirth, sd.Gender, sd.HolidayDaysRemaining  
FROM StaffDetails sd  
WHERE StaffID IN  
    (SELECT USER  
    FROM DUAL);
```

My problem is, is that I cannot find a way to join these two views to make a single table. In a perfect world, if a staff member with ID 301 logged on and queried the whole of the table, it would display six columns, the first row would have all of their data in, the second row would have three columns of StaffID 302's data in and so on and so forth.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

(Finally, just to show that I've had a go, I tried this query:

```
CREATE VIEW StaffDetailsForStaff AS  
SELECT sdfsm.StaffID, sdfsm.StaffName, sdfsm.StaffRole,  
    sxdfsx.DateOfBirth, sxdfsx.Gender, sxdfsx.HolidayDaysRemaining  
FROM StaffDetailsForStaffMutual sdfsm, StaffXDetailsForStaffX sxdfsx  
WHERE sdfsm.StaffID = sxdfsx.StaffID;
```

but when logged on as 301 and queried, it showed **only** 301's data and no-one else's!)

Comment: for your homework problem, look into VPD (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/DatabaseSecurityEnhancements10g.php#column_level_vdp_policy )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an [outer join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#i2054062)

```
CREATE VIEW StaffDetailsForStaff AS  
SELECT sdfsm.StaffID, sdfsm.StaffName, sdfsm.StaffRole,  
    sxdfsx.DateOfBirth, sxdfsx.Gender, sxdfsx.HolidayDaysRemaining  
FROM StaffDetailsForStaffMutual sdfsm LEFT JOIN StaffXDetailsForStaffX sxdfsx  
     ON sdfsm.StaffID = sxdfsx.StaffID;
```